# Optimize with PyMC3

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pymc3

### Problem Summary

I have been optimizing my function `VectorizedVcdfe`, and I am still trying to optimize it. This function is responsible for 99% of the slowness of another function `customFunc`. This `customFunc` is used in a PyMC3 code block.

Please help me optimize `VectorizedVcdfe`.

#### Function to optimize

```
def VectorizedVcdfe(self, x, dataVector, recip_h_times_lambda_vector):
    n = len(dataVector)

    differenceVector = x - dataVector

    stackedDiffVecAndRecipVec = pymc3.math.stack(differenceVector, recip_h_times_lambda_vector)

    erfcTerm  = 1. - pymc3.math.erf(self.neg_sqrt1_2 * pymc3.math.prod(stackedDiffVecAndRecipVec, axis=0))

    # Calc F_Hat
    F_Hat = (1. / float(n)) * pymc3.math.sum(0.5 * erfcTerm)

    # Return F_Hat
    return(F_Hat)
```

#### Arguments/variables

`x` is a TensorVariable.

`dataVector` is a 1Xn numpy matrix.

`recip_h_times_lambda_vector` is also a 1Xn numpy matrix.

`neg_sqrt1_2` is a scalar constant.

#### How `customFunc` is used

```
with pymc3.Model() as model:
    # Create likelihood
    like = pymc3.DensityDist('X', customFunc, shape=2)

    # Make samples
    step = pymc3.NUTS()
    trace = pymc3.sample(2000, tune=1000, init=None, step=step, cores=2)
```

#### EDIT:

To answer commenters, random values are OK for both `dataVector` and 
`recip_h_times_lambda_vector` for the purposes of doing this optimization. In reality, `recip_h_times_lambda_vector` is dependent on `dataVector` and a scalar parameter `h`.

Some commenters were wondering about `customFunc`, so here it is...

```
def customFunc(X):
    Y = []
    for j in range(2):
        x_j = X[j]
        F_x_j = fittedKdEstimator.VCDFE(x_j)
        y_j = myPPF(F_x_j)
        Y.append(y_j)

    logLikelihood = 0.
    recipSqrtTwoPi = 1. / math.sqrt(2. * math.pi)

    for j in range(2):
        y_j = Y[j]
        logLikelihood += pymc3.math.log(recipSqrtTwoPi * pymc3.math.exp(y_j * y_j / -2.))

    return(pymc3.math.exp(logLikelihood))
```

The global variable `fittedKdEstimator` is an instance of the class that contains the functions `VectorizedVcdfe` and `VCDFE`.

Here is the Python code for `VCDFE`...

```
def VCDFE(self, x):
    if not self.beenFit: raise Exception("Must first fit to data")

    return(self.VectorizedVcdfe(x, self.__dataVector, self.__recip_h_times_lambda_vector))
```

On a separate note, the function `myPPF` is my implementation of the standard normal "percent-point function" (AKA: "quantile function"). I have timed the `customFunc`, and `myPPF` takes a fraction of the entire time. The vast majority of time is consumed by `VectorizedVcdfe`.

Last but not least, a typical value for `n` may range from 10,000 to 100,000.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to provide code for `customFunc` :) And honestly, provide some examples of `dataVector` and `recip_h_times_lambda_vector` too. For example, if random values are OK, then say so. If `np.linspace` works, then use that.

Comment: At the very least, provide the value of `n`. The focus of optimization can be different for different input sizes.